# How to style and position buttons in slick?

Tags: slick.js

I am trying to make buttons and the "dot-menu" in slick slider visible.

My example in jsfiddle looks OK, though the "dot-menu" underneath the items is missing: [my slick example](http://jsfiddle.net/xdrsuygh/)

In "real live" my implementation looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>

     <style >
        .variants {
          cursor: pointer;
          border: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
          width: 192px;
          height: 223px;
          float: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="variants-container">
      <div class="variants">test</div>
      <div class="variants">test</div>
      <div class="variants">test</div>
      <div class="variants">test</div>
    </div>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.variants-container').slick({
          infinite: true,
          slidesToShow: 3,
          slidesToScroll: 3
        });
      </script>

</body>
</html>
```

There are buttons on top of the item set instead of a nice round buttons valigned and on top of the left item.

[image: without slick/slick-theme.css]

Desired implementation:

[image]

How can I acchive the desired state of the buttons and also show dot indicators on the bottom of each set?

Answer (score 0):

The below code works as your expecting, the problem was you're including the jquery files twice, once in the head and once at the end of the body. Also you forgot to include the "slick-theme.css" after "slick.css"

To get the dots at the bottom of the carousel, according to the docs, simply add `dots: true` in settings

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css" />`

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css" />
<style>
html,
body {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #CCC;
}

.variants {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
  width: 192px;
  height: 223px;
  float: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="variants-container">
      <div class="variants">test</div>
      <div class="variants">test</div>
      <div class="variants">test</div>
      <div class="variants">test</div>
    </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.variants-container').slick({
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 3,
      dots: true
    });
  });
  
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be a working example, however on my computer copy/pasting the same code to an html file and opening in my browser the buttons are in the form of 2 characters (a with accent cironflex and a cross) in white which is the reason why the are not visible. Tried in different browsers. Also, how to get the dots on the bottom of the set?

Comment: @merlin I updated my answer, you should see the dots appear